# The other error about x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: openshift

When I installed okd4.5, running the openshift command prompts the error message as follows:
[root@bastion ~]# openshift-install --dir=/okdinstall/ wait-for bootstrap-complete   --log-level=debug

```
DEBUG OpenShift Installer 4.5.0-0.okd-2020-10-15-235428 

DEBUG Built from commit 63200c80c431b8dbaa06c0cc13282d819bd7e5f8 
INFO Waiting up to 20m0s for the Kubernetes API at https://api.okd.test1.com:6443... 
DEBUG Still waiting for the Kubernetes API: Get https://api.okd.test1.com:6443/version?timeout=32s: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kube-apiserver-lb-signer")
```

我的操作步骤如下：
52  hostnamectl set-hostname bastion

```
53  ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa

54  eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

55  ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

56  systemctl disable firewalld

57  systemctl stop firewalld

58  yum -y install wget vim etcd bind-utils

59  systemctl enable etcd --now

60  systemctl status etcd

61  wget https://github.com/coredns/coredns/releases/download/v1.6.9/coredns_1.6.9_linux_amd64.tgz

62  tar zxvf coredns_1.6.9_linux_amd64.tgz

63  mv coredns /usr/local/bin

64  useradd coredns -s /sbin/nologin

65  vim  /etc/systemd/system/coredns.service

66  mkdir /etc/coredns

67  vi /etc/coredns/Corefile

68  systemctl enable coredns --now

69  systemctl status coredns

70  alias etcdctlv3='ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl'

71  etcdctlv3 put /skydns/com/test1/okd/api '{"host":"172.16.121.13", "ttl":60}'

72  etcdctlv3 put /skydns/com/test1/okd/api-int '{"host":"172.16.121.13", "ttl":60}'

73  etcdctlv3 put /skydns/com/test1/okd/registry '{"host":"172.16.121.13", "ttl":60}'

74  etcdctlv3 put /skydns/com/test1/okd/etcd-1 '{"host":"172.16.121.14", "ttl":60}'

75  etcdctlv3 put /skydns/com/test1/okd/etcd-2 '{"host":"172.16.121.15", "ttl":60}'

76  etcdctlv3 put /skydns/com/test1/okd/etcd-3 '{"host":"172.16.121.16", "ttl":60}'

77  etcdctlv3 put /skydns/com/test1/okd/_tcp/_etcd-server-ssl/x1 '{"host":"etcd-1.okd.test1.com", "ttl":60, "priority":0, "weight":10, "port":2380}'

78  etcdctlv3 put /skydns/com/test1/okd/_tcp/_etcd-server-ssl/x1 '{"host":"etcd-2.okd.test1.com", "ttl":60, "priority":0, "weight":10, "port":2380}'

79  etcdctlv3 put /skydns/com/test1/okd/_tcp/_etcd-server-ssl/x1 '{"host":"etcd-3.okd.test1.com", "ttl":60, "priority":0, "weight":10, "port":2380}'

80  etcdctlv3 put /skydns/com/test1/okd/bastion '{"host":"172.16.121.13", "ttl":60}'

81  etcdctlv3 put /skydns/com/test1/okd/bootstrap '{"host":"172.16.121.19", "ttl":60}'

82  etcdctlv3 put /skydns/com/test1/okd/master1 '{"host":"172.16.121.14", "ttl":60}'

83  etcdctlv3 put /skydns/com/test1/okd/master2 '{"host":"172.16.121.15", "ttl":60}'

84  etcdctlv3 put /skydns/com/test1/okd/master3 '{"host":"172.16.121.16", "ttl":60}'

85   etcdctlv3 put /skydns/com/test1/okd/worker1 '{"host":"172.16.121.17", "ttl":60}'

86  etcdctlv3 put /skydns/com/test1/okd/worker2 '{"host":"172.16.121.18", "ttl":60}'

87  dig +short apps.okd.test1.com @127.0.0.1

88  dig +short master2.okd.test1.com @127.0.0.1

89  cat /etc/resolv.conf 

     search okd.test1.com  
     nameserver 172.16.121.13

90  yum -y install  haproxy

91  vim /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

92  systemctl enable haproxy && systemctl restart haproxy

93  systemctl status haproxy

94  netstat -anput | grep 6443

95  yum -y install net-tools

96  netstat -anput | grep 6443

97  netstat -anput | grep 22623

98  mkdir -p /opt/registry/{auth,certs,data}

99  mkdir /data

100  cd /opt/registry/certs

101  openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout ca.key -x509 -days 36500 -out ca.crt

102  openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout registry.okd.test1.com.key -out registry.okd.test1.com.csr -days 36500

103  openssl x509 -req -days 36500 -in registry.okd.test1.com.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out registry.okd.test1.com.crt

104  echo -n 'admin:Harbor12345' | base64 -w0

105  vim /root/pull-secret.json

106  yum -y install httpd-tools yum-utils telnet httpd epel-release podman

107  yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

108  yum -y install docker-ce docker-compose 

109  systemctl start docker && systemctl enable docker

110  systemctl status docker

111  cd /opt

112  wget https://github.com/goharbor/harbor/releases/download/v2.0.1/harbor-offline-installer-v2.0.1.tgz

121  tar -zxvf harbor-offline-installer-v2.0.1.tgz && rm -rf harbor-offline-installer-v2.0.1.tgz && cd harbor/

122  mv harbor.yml.tmpl harbor.yml

123  vim harbor.yml 

124  ./install.sh

125  mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.okd.test1.com

126  cp /opt/registry/certs/registry.okd.test1.com.crt
```

/etc/docker/certs.d/registry.okd.test1.com

```
127  cp /opt/registry/certs/ca.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/

128  update-ca-trust extrat

129  systemctl restart docker

130  netstat -anput | grep docker

131  curl -u admin:Harbor12345 -k https://registry.okd.test1.com:18443/v2/_catalog

132  wget https://github.com/openshift/okd/releases/download/4.5.0-0.okd-2020-10-15-235428/openshift-client-linux-4.5.0-0.okd-2020-10-15-235428.tar.gz

133  ll

134  cd /root/

135  ll

136  wget https://github.com/openshift/okd/releases/download/4.5.0-0.okd-2020-10-15-235428/openshift-install-linux-4.5.0-0.okd-2020-10-15-235428.tar.gz

137  ll

138  tar -zxvf openshift-client-linux-4.5.0-0.okd-2020-10-15-235428.tar.gz

139  cp oc kubectl /usr/local/bin/

140  oc version

141  tar -zxvf openshift-install-linux-4.5.0-0.okd-2020-10-15-235428.tar.gz

142  cp openshift-install /usr/local/bin/

143  openshift-install version

144  export OCP_RELEASE=4.5.0-0.okd

145  export LOCAL_REGISTRY='registry.okd.test1.com:18443'

146  export LOCAL_REPOSITORY='openshift/okd'

147  export PRODUCT_REPO='openshift'

148  export LOCAL_SECRET_JSON='/root/pull-secret.json'

149  export RELEASE_NAME='okd'

150  export ARCHITECTURE="2020-10-15-235428"

152  oc adm -a ${LOCAL_SECRET_JSON} release mirror --from=quay.io/${PRODUCT_REPO}/${RELEASE_NAME}:${OCP_RELEASE}-${ARCHITECTURE} --to=${LOCAL_REGISTRY}/${LOCAL_REPOSITORY} --to-release-image=${LOCAL_REGISTRY}/${LOCAL_REPOSITORY}:${OCP_RELEASE}-${ARCHITECTURE}

209  cd /root/

210  vim install-config.yaml

211  mkdir /okdinstall/

213  cp install-config.yaml /okdinstall/

214  openshift-install create manifests --dir=/okdinstall

215  sed -i 's/mastersSchedulable: true/mastersSchedulable: False/'
 /okdinstall/manifests/cluster-scheduler-02-config.yml

216  openshift-install create ignition-configs --dir=/okdinstall

217  mkdir /root/.kube/

218  cp /okdinstall/auth/kubeconfig ~/.kube/config

219  chmod -R 755 /okdinstall/*

220  mkdir /usr/share/nginx/html/ignition/

221  cp -rp /okdinstall/* /usr/share/nginx/html/ignition/

222  mkdir /usr/share/nginx/html/install/

223  openshift-install --dir=/okdinstall/ wait-for bootstrap-complete   --log-level=debug
```

设计到的文件内容如下：
cat /root/pull-secret.json

```
{
  "auths": {
    "registry.okd.test1.com:18443": { 
      "auth": "YWRtaW46SGFyYm9yMTIzNDU=", 
      "email": ""
    }
  }
}
cat /root/install-config.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
baseDomain: test1.com        
compute:
- hyperthreading: Enabled 
  name: worker
  replicas: 0               
controlPlane:
  hyperthreading: Enabled
  name: master
  replicas: 3                   
metadata:
  name: okd                   
networking:
  clusterNetwork:
  - cidr: 10.128.0.0/14         
    hostPrefix: 23             
  networkType: OpenShiftSDN  
  serviceNetwork: 
  - 172.30.0.0/16              
platform:
  none: {}                     
fips: false

sshKey: 'ssh-rsa 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 root@bastion'

pullSecret: '{"auths":{"registry.okd.test1.com:18443": {"auth": "YWRtaW46SGFyYm9yMTIzNDU=","email": ""}}}'
imageContentSources:
- mirrors:
  - registry.okd.test1.com:18443/openshift/okd
  source: quay.io/openshift/okd
- mirrors:
  - registry.okd.test1.com:18443/openshift/okd
  source: quay.io/openshift/okd-content
 # 密钥文件信息来自于 /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.okd.test1.com/registry.okd.test1.com.crt
additionalTrustBundle: |
  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  MIIFejCCA2ICCQCIsY5LihXiSDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADB+MQswCQYDVQQGEwJD
  TjELMAkGA1UECAwCQkoxCzAJBgNVBAcMAkJKMQ0wCwYDVQQKDARURVNUMQ0wCwYD
  VQQLDARURVNUMRgwFgYDVQQDDA8qLm9rZC50ZXN0MS5jb20xHTAbBgkqhkiG9w0B
  CQEWDnRlc3RAdGVzdDEuY29tMCAXDTIxMDgxMDExMDc0MloYDzIxMjEwNzE3MTEw
  NzQyWjB+MQswCQYDVQQGEwJDTjELMAkGA1UECAwCQkoxCzAJBgNVBAcMAkJKMQ0w
  CwYDVQQKDARURVNUMQ0wCwYDVQQLDARURVNUMRgwFgYDVQQDDA8qLm9rZC50ZXN0
  MS5jb20xHTAbBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWDnRlc3RAdGVzdDEuY29tMIICIjANBgkqhkiG
  9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEA2PpMgCdjfZd2ww+uYjxrN3Wbl5qxKWJYTtX9
  uI0/37g1Bz09XSVB4zW3WHmqCBwr1ad6/S92vv0HHtnJDP+PcoP6FsnBagPxxwCC
  bIF4svkwSG7bQkUZcFbQ+S3Tqo8cHBOeSW4fzFPYO7QKF3Bhmq1tqYO5cqPrlOdb
  1+L31Etx+P6P7+/XBzr4CUckTsdQXoEIcKFTQfrn9NMAeSscFk5Qw76DPhj4tJbe
  Rx+ebpwgQodrsr8C9qn8Ebj6n1oz5S/mer6CeNR4M2HTdoBqUP0eHbLAyBzrzXwK
  0OTqn7+El5DyA86yY99ag8SLsNjHc1J4PYPLbNuk/UvathsLAWQZjeyq+Zyf4KQk
  PvXi8wlKXik9eAAtL/fx3jNoAm57f0qdc7Z3+e8X4cr9wvNerC7IVV8OSRMsxlze
  w5c0YqP3kex9UV3f4FpKBJEZI9k1Gcg911ffl5dj7wDunj2wzyzprhjWvdswkCux
  5kJfPZhgoBUK0DRmoW7b9r00YsMYodI05MuEVG/KiRlfQn3/xa0NEAqxJbM+zbOJ
  rJmQLV2mJQjh3FgIc99L0CFPaoaANPi1t3hYnFRiWxRaDhxnNUaCb6QUMp+ZphbX
  eRYmZ2DqGB91pFliT8MSxlBqcTq+AgUE7IKa0Tu9QZxN9ve1DlXJQi+LIenC3iZs
  7OMQKwUCAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAgEAZZ/8l4daDzyxwIALkoepjbKi
  ozIp/Oz9HRvlVUM1rM37zceo3xumP8T1AWvr/z9tLei5/HMgqAbbegFx+Y0Rdwyt
  DdHk4UFOcGBomFnA0CYXOywKIOo5qByOthBu0GF7quns4MTpPUN0sXkYDAoBRPLB
  Wsan71DBAa6GN/kvu5eXN3SZeiAz4Ou3Yk43++Iy5NNWNjB37GNdtL9LRdtYGaVb
  /kUiFdPL2S9gtex/EdWFqsZrN/0VNGRD8/bLQlavIFwYYz7zaMt7UxT7q7v2prkK
  FF7GZiDJZb0NeHDLnyoP0yHuqefnKV7oV1aBqYh3Y6zk16S6DIl8WKfCgEaHSwB+
  ESGxKU42NCWgTw8ollXHMjezT1C6LAzLGuMToJXVQzYhoacGLJKtkCcKwYV/df4z
  /Z5s1ECphLLetR8JyByhDOzk48tZyXrMN3DvtIfVsbR5cRqZrW5KK6gRKTm1Stsq
  TLB9wLtn/ytA9HaMijsudPB/7k/Q3Mm4G3WfnLlpQpc9oQeG/32dEq2FM3Ykp/YX
  UQvTh6MEjj8XTHe6FT1yJNMqcQL/oct3bTRc8kegtzgELgpUGMGBnlFtIICBleVx
  2/lzFrU7P08poKuZ+1loG4rZG9vxsWRX/MZ2AVi+c2jQ9qRwnD5as+YoUyFw42Xx
  vOouHXd0lg7onR1v82M=
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----
备注：我的系统是centos7.9
```